# java: ArrayList<Object[]> how set length of Object[]?

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I set the length of each array Object[] in advance?
For example:

```
 ArrayList<Object[]> obj=new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

How do I set the length of the array Object [] before inserting the data?

Comment: `obj.add(new Object[length]);` ?

Comment: The Arraylist can take various `Object[]` of varying lengths. Isn't this the advantage here? Why do you want to restrict that by fixing the size of each `Object[]` as the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to initialize the `Object[]` then add it to the `ArrayList`

**Example:**

```
Object[] objs = new Object[size];// set the size that you want
//add data to objs
obj.add(objs);
```

**Note** that you can set a various `Object[]` to `ArrayList` with different sizes.

```
Object[] objs2 = new Object[anotherSize];// set the size that you want
//add data to objs2
obj.add(objs2);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how you set the size of array of objects

```
Object[] array = new Object[size];
```

And that's how you set size of ArrayList

```
List<Object[]> obj = new ArrayList<Object[]>(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Object[]>` is a list of arrays. Each array in the list can have a different length.

For instance, with an array of length 10 and an array of length 20:

```
Object[] array0 = new Object[10];
Object[] array1 = new Object[20];
obj.add(array0);   
obj.add(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't. The ArrayList contains a list of references to array-objects and not the array-objects itself. So the list only knows that it has a couple of arrays, but does not know anything about these objects itself.

To set the length of the arrays you need to define them one by one:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> list=new ArrayList<Object[]>();
Object[] arr1 = new Object[10];
Object[] arr2 = new Object[10];
Object[] arr3 = new Object[5];
list.add(arr1);
list.add(arr2);
list.add(arr3);
```

If you really want to limit which arrays you want to store in the list, you might want to write an [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for the kind of objects you want to store in the list.